# How can you embed a date format into a string and get Powershell to dynamically populate the datetime using the specified format?

Tags: regex, powershell, datetime

I have text which I'd like to embed a recognizable string containing the desired date format.

For example, I'd like to store the string:

"The current date time in our desired format is %date:yyyyMMdd%"

but have it displayed as

"The current date time in our desired format is 20190108"

```
$texttoreplace = "The current date time in our desired format is %date:yyyyMMdd%"
$texttoreplace -replace "(%DATE)(.*)(%)", (get-date -format $2)
```

Attempting to pass the second group from the -replace is getting ignored.

The current date time in our desired format is 01/08/2019 13:54:07

How can the value of $2 get parsed so that the format of yyyyMMdd is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i can tell, you cannot have a calculated value in a `-replace` replacement text. [*frown*] however, you can use `-match` and the `$Matches` automatic variable to get to the same end. something like this ...

```
$texttoreplace = "The current date time in our desired format is %date:yyyyMMdd%"
[void]($texttoreplace -match '%date:(.*)%')
$AfterReplacement = $texttoreplace -replace '%date:.+%', (Get-Date -Format $Matches[1])

$AfterReplacement
```

output ...

```
The current date time in our desired format is 20190108
```

Comment: @AlexanderDawson - kool! you are most welcome ... glad to help! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

This may be a more efficient/cleaner way of doing it. simply use the -format parameter of get-date as a variable, and call that variable in your output:

```
$datetime = Get-date -Format yyyyMMdd
$dateformat = Write-Output -InputObject "The current date/time in our desired format is $datetime"
$dateformat

C:\> The current date/time in our desired format is 20190109
```

I would go one further and actually show the date format as both as your output makes no distiction between days or months and this will be confusing and wont be explicit should the current date be <12 for both days and months:

```
$datetime = Get-date -Format yyyyMMdd
$dateformat = Write-Output -InputObject "The current date/time in our desired format(yyyyMMdd) is $datetime"
$dateformat

C:\> The current date/time in our desired format(yyyyMMdd) is 20190109
```